# Golang Gin: SaveUploadedFile is not able to save file properly

Tags: go, gzip, tar, multipart, go-gin

I'm trying to save a `multipart` uploaded file in local file system of the server using the method: `SaveUploadedFile` defined for `gin.Context`. It is working fine for images but when trying to save a file of type `.tgz` the file size is reducing a lot and thus not saving the file properly. It's getting corrupt. Pls let me know what I might be doing wrong. The file being uploaded is of size 33KB. But when saving in local it's showing 14KB. Code below

```
    multipartFileHeader, err := c.FormFile("file")
    if err != nil {
        c.AbortWithStatusJSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{
            "message": "No file is received",
        })
        return "", err
    }
    fmt.Println("file size")
    fmt.Println(multipartFileHeader.Size)
    extension := filepath.Ext(multipartFileHeader.Filename)
    newFileName := uuid.New().String() + extension
    localTargetFilePath := "/tmp/" + newFileName
    if err := c.SaveUploadedFile(multipartFileHeader, localTargetFilePath); err != nil {
        c.AbortWithStatusJSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{
            "message": "Unable to save the file",
        })
        return "", err
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? Or are you concluding that it's not working simply due to the smaller file size? The `z` in `tgz` means compressed. The data is _supposed_ to get smaller if it's not already compressed. Images are already compressed, and so can't be compressed further.

Comment: @MarkAdler I'm uploading a .tgz file itself. My intention is just to save it in the local filesystem without any further compression. the method in question: `SaveUploadedFile` should just save the file in local. But I am not getting any clue why it's reducing the file size and making it corrupt.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "making it corrupt"?